# How Is C# Able To Infer Overload From Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, language-lawyer, expression, type-inference

Recently I was surprised that a particular piece of syntax in C# worked in a sort of "magical" way. This syntax had multiple overloads, only differentiated by the generic type in an `Action<T>` or `Func<T>` parameter. It may be bias from being more familiar with C++ syntax but it was surprising to me that msbuild was able to correctly choose the overload based solely on a lambda expression without even needing to specify the type of the lambda parameter.

```
using System;

namespace Test1;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Picks overload #1 - somehow knows that x must be an int.
        Accept(x => x = 1);

        // Picks overload #2 - somehow knows that x must be a string.
        Accept(x => x.ToLower());
    }
    
    // Overload #1
    private static void Accept(Action<int> action) => action(0);

    // Overload #2
    private static void Accept(Action<string> action) => action("abc");
}
```

It is interesting to me how `x => x = 1` is correctly inferred to be `Overload #1` and `x => x.ToLower()` is correctly inferred to be `Overload #2`. I would have assumed that I would have had to be explicit about the lambda expression's type. For example, `Accept((int x) => x = 1);` and `Accept((string x) => x.ToLower());`.

Is there anything in the C# standard or elsewhere that would be able to explain how this is happening and perhaps what conditions or rules this inference can occur under?

Answer (score 2):

The types are inferred by the usage.  While an int can be converted to a string, it can't be done implicitly so the first option is inferred by a compatible assignment.  An int also doesn't have a .ToLower() extension method so the second option can be inferred as the string type.  On the other hand if your types were more ambiguous, you would get an error.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Produces Error CS0121
    Accept(x => x = 1);
}
    
// Overload #1
private static void Accept(Action<int> action) => action(0);

// Overload #2
private static void Accept(Action<long> action) => action(1L);
```

Comment: Further proof: `Accept(x => x.ToString());` is a compiler error

Answer (score 2):

The compiler (which is not MSBuild, BTW) simply searches for a **single** method signature that will allow the program to compile. If it finds 0 matches it emits an error telling you that it couldn't find one; if it finds 2 or more possible matches, it will tell you to specify your arguments' types to allow it to make that single match.

Comment: The compilers name is Roslyn, in case anyone was curious.